# Codenameone Ad component

Tags: codenameone

I have a border layout with absolute center.
The south container has three element.
Ad and two buttons.
Now, when the page loads the ad component is empty so it takes no space and all the elements are drawn to the screen.
When the ad loads, all the components above are shifted.
Is there a workaround to this issue ?
Thanks,
Sanket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main focus of Codename One is on the new [ad component based on Google Play ads](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/12/adding-google-play-ads.html). So changes to the old ad component probably won't happen since its architecture is problematic with newer ad platforms.

You can reserve space for the ad by setting its preferred size but that is problematic since you will be hardcoding the sizes of the ads.

Comment: Even the Vserv ad that loads at startup hangs sometimes. Doesnt let the user skip

Comment: We've actually had a complaint about this from an enterprise account today by chance. We fixed an issue there. It should be in the servers sometime next week.